# WPF, what kind of controls will handle MouseLeftButtonDown event?

Tags: wpf, routed-events

I have a DataGridControl,and its cell's DataTemplate overwritten to TextBoxs,by clicking outside the cells but still on the DataGrid, I want the TextBox to lose Keyboard focus so that it can Commit the change, but it seems the DataGrid won't handle the MouseLeftButtonDown event, so I have to manually add a handler to the Grid,and in the handler:

```
        e.Handled = true;
        Keyboard.Focus( sender as UIElement );
```

to make the parent panel "focusable".

By using Snoop, I notice that controls like TextBox, Button are capable of handle MosueLeftButtonDown event, while Panels are not,event if set "Focusable" property to "True". Does anyone know the reason behind this, Thanks.

**To simplify the situation**: suppose we have a TextBox and a Button on a Grid:

```
<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
    <TextBox Height="25" Margin="50" Text="abcd"/>
    <Button  Height="25" Margin="50,100,50,0"></Button>
</Grid>
```

when I click on the TextBox, it gets KeyBoard focus, when I click the blank area of the Grid, I want the TextBox to lose focus, the problem is Grid is not focusable compared with TextBoxes and Buttons.

[image]

Comment: The event system of WPF is rather versatile. Anything derives from UIElement is able to handle Mouse/Keyboard and other kind of events. The reason behind you can't "listen" for events on a Panel, is probably because a visual "without any color" (i.e. Null background or so) by default does not handle events. Please, note that a Transparent color DOES handle events: that's a very common way to catch events without affecting the visual result.

Comment: Thanks Mario, the problem here is not the container Panel cannot listen for Mouse events, but by default, it can not get Keyboard focus responding to MouseDown event on it,Keyboard focus is still on Texbox in DatagridCell.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Panel shows that Panel can handle mouse events:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel_events(v=vs.110).aspx